# Comparing an int value to a different type in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm currently working on a project and I'm stuck at this point. Basically I'm trying to figure out how to compare a type: Key to a type: Int. From the code, here.theKey and theKey2 are type Key and theKey1 takes key as an argument, gets the hashcode, and then gets used to find the same hashcode within the BST named 'here'. The issue that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to compare the value for here.theKey to theKey1 which is an int.

Here is the method:

```
    public Value get(Key key)
    {
        int theKey1 = hash(key);
        TreeNode here = Tree;
        while (here != null)
        {
            int theKey2=here.theKey;


            if(theKey1 < theKey2 )
            {
            here = here.left;
            }
            else if(theKey1>theKey2)
                here = here.right;
            else
            {
                return here.value;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value associated with the key not found");
    }
```

I've tried to use compareTo but since theKey1 is type Int, I was getting an error. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't this line `int theKey2=here.theKey;` be `int theKey2=hash(here.theKey);` ?

Comment: `int theKey2 = hash(here.theKey);`, but what exactly is the point of a BST that is ordered on hashcodes?

Comment: The project is to write a program that uses a Hashtable with chaining to handle collisions and a BST in place of arrays.

Comment: But the BST needs to be ordered on the key, not the hashcode. It is there to provide *O(log(N))* access to all the elements *with the same hashcode.* You need to make `Key` implement `Comparable<Key>` and use `Key.compareTo()`. NB This is not a syntax question.

Comment: Convert the keys to same type and compare it...

Comment: @Dani Compare them how?

Comment: Are you sure that "here.theKey" returns an int???, I think this method should return a key, not an int

Answer (score 0):

Hashing the key here is pointless. The BST in your hash table consists of elements all of which have the same hash code. You need to ensure `Key implements Comparable<Key>` and use `Key.compareTo()`.

Answer (score -1):

You already have the answer in your hand. In the code you want the references of type `Key` only to take their `hash`. So why don't you convert all the `Key`s into their hashes and compare those hashes when needed?

Like

converting the first expression in the while loop to `int theKey2=hash(here.theKey);`

I see another problem too in the code. If the conditions of `if` or `else if` in the loop evaluates to true, after executing the corresponding block, the control will come directly to the `throw` statement. Thus the method will not branch to the child nodes of the root. So put `continue` statements as the last line of your `if` and `else if` blocks.

Comment: Hashing these particular keys will always yield the same hashcode, which makes the entire BST pointless.